# How to insert entries on a production server to the database deployed by AWS?

Tags: python, database, django, amazon-web-services, production

Is it possible to run the Django's manage.py shell on the terminal to insert some entries to my database, which is deployed on aws? 
Can I do this being connected through ssh? 
I tried as always running `python manage.py shell`and obviously it didn't work, I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: what is your backend database? Also, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429975/django-with-mssql-giving-error-databasewrapper-object-has-no-attribute-datab

Comment: How about this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315750/attributeerror-databasewrapper-object-has-no-attribute-database Also, my guess could be you might have not installed python-mysql binding, or a version conflict of the binding if you have already installed it.